# How to process a large delta table with UDF?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions, databricks, delta-lake

I have a delta table with about 300 billion rows. Now I am performing some operations on a column using UDF and creating another column

My code is something like this

```
def my_udf(data):
    return pass
       
 
udf_func = udf(my_udf, StringType())
data = spark.sql("""SELECT * FROM large_table """)
data = data.withColumn('new_column', udf_func(data.value))
```

The issue now is this take a long amount of time as Spark will process all 300 billion rows and then write the output. Is there a way where we can do some Mirco batching and write output of those regularly to the output delta table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first rule usually is to avoid UDFs as much of possible - what kind of transformation do you need to perform that isn't available in the Spark itself?

Second rule - if you can't avoid using UDF, at least use [Pandas UDFs](https://databricks.com/blog/2020/05/20/new-pandas-udfs-and-python-type-hints-in-the-upcoming-release-of-apache-spark-3-0.html) that process data in batches, and don't have so big serialization/deserialization overhead - usual UDFs are handling data row by row, encoding & decoding data for each of them.

If your table was built over the time, and consists of many files, you can try to use Spark Structured Streaming with `Trigger.AvailableNow` (requires DBR 10.3 or 10.4), something like this:

```py
maxNumFiles = 10 # max number of parquet files processed at once
df = spark.readStream \
  .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", maxNumFiles) \ 
  .table("large_table")
df = df.withColumn('new_column', udf_func(data.value))
df.writeStream \
  .option("checkpointLocation", "/some/path") \
  .trigger(availableNow=True) \
  .toTable("my_destination_table")
```

this will read the source table chunk by chunk, apply your transformation, and write data into a destination table.

Comment: I decode a Thrift binary to JSON so created a UDF for that

Comment: Use PandasUDFs at least - it’s significantly faster

Comment: If I use Pandas UDF, that process this in batch. But as we are reading the table in stream wouldn't the advantage of pandas udf be nullified?

Comment: No. Pandas UDFs are working in chunks of 10k records (by default), there is no differences between batch and stream in this case, as streaming is microbatch anyway

Comment: But inside my Pandas UDF I still have to do `map` as I need to access each row individually, does it still make sense to use Pandas UDF?

Comment: It’s all about bulk serialization and deserialization as opposed to row by row